# AngularJS: How to update service properties while keeping logic in controller?

Tags: angularjs

A typical service might look like this:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('module').service('SomeService', SomeService);

    SomeService.$inject = ['$http'];

    function SomeService($http) {
        var service = {
            login: login,
            logout: logout,
            userState: null //object for logged in status, points etc (is there a convention for what to initialize this to?)
        }

        return service;

        login(){ //$http implementation }
        logout(){ //implementation }
    }
})();
```

It makes sense that `login` would modify `userState`, but how can I do that from within the service. Since `login` is hoisted to the top of `SomeService` constructor, it will not have access to `service.userState`. The alternative would be to place logic to modify `userState` in the controller... In other words, return the $http login promise and then have the controller set the `userState` with `SomeService.user.loggedIn = true`, but would that be considered bad since now the controller determines whether or not the user is logged in? Shouldn't that logic belong in the service instead?

One thing I can think of are to use function expressions / IIFE - I don't want to do this since that involves bringing implementation details to the top of the file.

Comment: _Since login is hoisted to the top of SomeService constructor, it will not have access to service.userState._ - You are wrong about this statement. When you call login function, service object would be initialized already and you can access service.userState variable inside login function. It is good practice to update userState variable in login method itself.

Comment: As per my understanding, __Yes, it has__. `The login method can access  service.userState_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want `userState` to be edited out of the service, you just need a getter function to get the value if my understanding is correct.

(function() {
    angular.module('module').service('SomeService', SomeService);

```
SomeService.$inject = ['$http'];

function SomeService($http) {
    var userState = null;
    var service = {
        login: login,
        logout: logout,
        getUserState: getUserState
    }

    return service;

    function login(){ //$http implementation and you can use $promise to change userState to true here }
    function logout(){ //implementation and you can use $promise to change userState to null here }
    function getUserState(){ return userState; }
}
```

})();

Comment: But wouldn't the getter be hoisted before userState is initialized and thus always return undefined?

Comment: the getter will always give your the current value of `userState`, it's a closure. if you dont login, it will return null as it is initialized to null. if you change the userState in the callback of login, then call getter again, it will give you true

Comment: Ah, you are right. It's a closure that has access to constructor context. Thanks!